# Web based Oracle Scene Builder analog

Tags: web, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to provide an ability to create simple java and javafx applications to the users on my website. I've found excellent code editor (Ace) but I don't know how to provide FXML design tool to the Web users.

Is there any options?

**ADD** I want the users to use this interface builder without any additional requirements like Java 8 or something

Answer (score 0):

How to host SceneBuilder in a web page (requires Java 8):

1. Build [SceneBuilder from it's source](https://community.oracle.com/message/11290332).
2. Package it as a [Browser Embedded Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#BABJHEJA).
3. Host your packaged application on the Internet and direct web users to its URL.

Other than using a fork of SceneBuilder for your project, I don't know of any other feasible way to provide visual FXML editing capabilities.  I would certainly not recommend trying to create from scratch your own FXML visual editor written in either Java or JavaScript.

Comment: It looks like it works only with Java 8, and all of my client must have Java 8 installed

Comment: Yes.  If you have particular constraints, you should list them in your question.  My guess is that the question as it currently stands is too open ended and may get closed or ignored.

Comment: I've tried to build it with Java 7 but no luck :( I'll to use `Docker` with VNC

Comment: Yes Open Source Scene Builder requires Java 8 minimum both to build and to run.